# HTTP GET omitting query string parameters

Tags: ajax, forms, http, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am attempting to give signed URLs to authenticated users on my website to enable them to download content from Amazon S3. I generate the URLs on the server and send them to the client via AJAX. I then generate an HTML form, and update the action of that form to be the signed URL. I then submit the form using jQuery. The problem is that when I inspect the request, parts of the URL are being omitted, specifically the query string parameters.

```
https://xxx.s3.amazonaws.com/abc123?AWSAccessKeyId=idkey&Expires=1391218513&Signature=sig
```

turns into just:

```
https://xxx.s3.amazonaws.com/abc123?
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: It appears query strings params are passed by hidden input fields embedded in forms. Hopefully this will fix my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to append query string parameters to a form is like so

```
<form action="/index" method="GET">
   <input type="hidden" name="a" value="1" />
   <input type="hidden" name="b" value="2" />
</form>
```

This will generate the URL `"http://<domain>/index?a=1&b=2"`